Excel 365 I want to trim excess character and ASCII 160. In a columm of data
I found a macro that makes it good on a cell. I would like it to work on a column with 75000 rows.
Sub test() 
    Dim a$, b$, c$, i As Integer 
    a$ = Range("A1").Value 
    For i = 1 To Len(a$) 
        b$ = Mid(a$, i, 1) 
        If b$ Like "[A-Z,a-z,0-9]" Then 
            c$ = c$ & b$ 
        End If 
    Next i 
    Range("A2").Value = c$ 
End Sub


It seems you know which characters you want to keep. Using VBA, you could use Regular Expressions to do the replacement:
Option Explicit
Sub removeChars()

'declare variables
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range, c As Range
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vRes As Variant
    Dim I As Long
    Dim re As Object

'set the range to process
'work in arrays for increased speed
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set rng = Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    vSrc = rng
    ReDim vRes(1 To UBound(vSrc), 1 To 1)
End With

'use regular expressions to keep the desired characters
With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    .Pattern = "[^0-9A-Z]"
    .ignorecase = True
    .Global = True
    For I = 1 To UBound(vSrc, 1)
        vRes(I, 1) = .Replace(vSrc(I, 1), "")
    Next I
End With

'write the results back to the original range
'could write it to a different range if needed for debugging
rng = vRes
End Sub

This can also be done using a worksheet formula if you have 365.
Change the d line to reflect the range to process.
The results will SPILL down from wherever you put the formula.
=LET(
    d, A1:A1000,
    _allowed, VSTACK(
        CHAR(SEQUENCE(26, , 65)),
        CHAR(SEQUENCE(26, , 97)),
        CHAR(SEQUENCE(10, , 48))
    ),
    BYROW(
        d,
        LAMBDA(arr,
            REDUCE(
                "",
                MID(arr, SEQUENCE(LEN(arr)), 1),
                LAMBDA(a, b, IF(OR(b = _allowed), a & b, a))
            )
        )
    )
)

Useful reference: How to use Regular Expressions (Regex) in Microsoft Excel both in-cell and loops

Another reference with regard to the arrays, added as a comment since it is not an SO link, from the late Chip Pearson: Arrays and Ranges

upvoted because it shows a couple ways, and of course mentions good old Chip! I'll put a separate answer just because I like all functions that can be added to library without forgetting stuff and can call in many ways then

I tried the macro does not work I alsi tried the formula it says missing arguments

@Mike Macro -- doesn't work is too vague a statement. Since both work properly here, I suspect you have not properly adapted the macro and the formula to your actual data. But since you chose to provide no examples of your data nor how you tried to adapt the code/formula I provided to your data, it is not possible to advise you.

If you know the set of characters that need to be replaced, you can use Excel's Replace function. It might be more efficient than check all chars on a column.
Sub Macro1()
    Dim aKey: aKey = Array(Chr(160), Chr(10)) ' expand as needed
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To UBound(aKey)
        Columns("A:A").Replace What:=aKey(i), Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2
    Next
End Sub


I tried the macro but does not work

What does not work mean? Pls share sample data.
Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?.
Please create MD table with online tool Table Generator.

Put a couple functions in a VBA module and add to your libraries. You can always just keep using the generic and change the regex:
Public Function GenericRegExStripper(inputParam As Variant, re As Object) As Variant
If VarType(inputParam) = vbString Then
    GenericRegExStripper = re.Replace(inputParam, "")    ' done!
    Exit Function
End If

Dim s As Variant
If TypeName(s) = "Range" Then
    s = inputParam.Value 'best change to array here and pass to following logic
Else
    s = inputParam
End If

If VarType(s) > vbArray Then    'array of some sort
    Dim arrLen As Long
    arrLen = UBound(s) - LBound(s) + 1
    'is there a second dimension?
    Dim dim2 As Long
On Error Resume Next
    dim2 = UBound(s, 2) - LBound(s, 2) + 1
On Error GoTo 0
    
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim index As Long, j As Long, counter As Long
    If dim2 = 0 Then    '1d array
        ReDim arr(0 To arrLen - 1) As String    'return a 1d array
        counter = 0
    Else    'return array size as put in (but we'll just go for 1-based as an assumption of ranges)
        ReDim arr(1 To arrLen, 1 To dim2) As String
        counter = 1
    End If
    
    For index = LBound(s) To UBound(s)
        If dim2 = 0 Then    '1d array
            arr(counter) = re.Replace(s(index), "")
        Else
            For j = 1 To dim2
                arr(counter, j) = re.Replace(s(index, j), "")
            Next j
        End If
        counter = counter + 1
    Next index
    
    GenericRegExStripper = arr
    Exit Function
Else
    'this might be changed to reject other outputs depending on the scenario
    GenericRegExStripper = re.Replace(CStr(inputParam), "")
End If
End Function


Public Function StripAllNonAlphaNumerics(s As Variant) As Variant
Static RegEx_alphanumeric As Object    'RegExp
If RegEx_alphanumeric Is Nothing Then
    Set RegEx_alphanumeric = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")    'New RegExp
    RegEx_alphanumeric.Pattern = "[^A-Za-z0-9]" 'all non-alphanumerics will be stripped
    RegEx_alphanumeric.Global = True
End If

StripAllNonAlphaNumerics = GenericRegExStripper(s, RegEx_alphanumeric)

End Function


I tried it does nothing

Ron Rosenfield's post shows you a simple way. There must be something wrong at your end, as these codes work as per description. The function is meant to be called by another sub in your case. Sorry but there's a learning curve to VBA, and I don't have the bandwidth for this. I just put answers if I can quickly put something out there

I tried the other suggestion and I got it to work

I tried the macro but does not work
